# How does the Intel ICH*R storage controller detect and fix errors in a RAID1 array on a full scan?

Tags: raid, sata

In Intel's RST tool to manage ICH*R arrays, there is an option for RAID1 arrays to "scan and fix" errors, which starts a job to scan the entire array.

So detecting errors with a high degree of confidence without any additional metadata should be easy -- compare the data on each disk and see if there is a difference.

But as for fixing errors, without some sort of checksum or parity, I do not know how RST would decide which set of data is correct.  And since it's widely reported individual disks from a ICH*R RAID1 array are fully compatible and can be read by standard SATA controllers, I assume there is no special format being used on disk.

Given the above, I am confused how the repair functionality actually works, and looking for more information.

Comment: What do you mean "how"? Intel RST likely catches errors, likely comparing to what it attempted to write and what was actually written.

Comment: @Ramhound The RST "scan and fix" option kicks off a full disk scan.  I'm not talking about anything that is done on active use.  Edited for clarity.

Comment: If it's scanning and fixing the data, there is at least one possibility, that can be used to accomplish that task.  One is to attempt the read multiple times, to determine if there is a disk error, and if one is detected use a prediction algorithm to determine what the bit should be.  Doing something like that works better when you can scan the entire disk and have sole access to the disk, since changing the data, while you are attempting to find the error would mean you are there all day.  Since this is likely handled by the Intel RST service it's likely more subtle than that method.

Answer (score 0):

Two-disk RAID1 indeed can only detect, but not correct errors if it has no further information, but modern disks have their own checksums and return a read error if the data has been damaged. The RAID controller will then rewrite the broken sector from a good copy, and the drive will remap the sector to a spare.

Comment: Is there more information on how these checksums work?  Specifically I am wondering, in cases of bit rot, does the drive signal an error on read and makes a best effort, or are the classes of bit rot errors that are undetectable to the hardware despite checksums?  I've seen cases of bit rot being corrected by ZFS integrity scans that seemingly had no associated signalled errors in system logs.

Comment: @Chuu, the drive will get noisy data from the disk, and use the checksums to determine which bits were flipped, then silently correct them if possible. Up to a certain threshold, no further action is taken, beyond that, the sector is rewritten with the restored data. If it is not possible to determine which bits were affected, a read error is generated (after a certain number of retries). Silent bit rot can happen only when the sector has so many errors that interpreting it as a sector with different contents is more likely, and that interpretation has fewer changes than the threshold.

Comment: The undetected case is rather unlikely though, because the "detectable, but uncorrectable" area between valid encodings is larger than the valid encodings, so ZFS rewriting sectors is usually indicative of bad RAM, not bad disks.